# "icon-bar" in twitter bootstrap navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot understand what the following code means in terms of `icon-bar`:

```html
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

What is `icon-bar` for? Why are there three similar instances of it?

This code is in the navigation bar section:

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: It is to create a button with three horizontal lines. This button is displayed when the screen width is small and the nav-bar collapses. When you click on it, the nav-bar expands.

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal, you are correct, but consider making this an answer instead of a comment!

Answer (score 132, accepted):

`icon-bar` is used for responsive layouts to create a button that looks like ≡ on narrow browser screens. You can resize your browser window (by making it narrow) to see how the navbar is replaced by that button.

The three `span` tags create three horizontal lines that look like a button, commonly known as the "burger" icon.

Take a look at `icon-bar` in `bootstrap.css`:

```
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

It is a block structure, so it is aligned line by line. The `background-color` is set to be [gray80](http://www.color-hex.com/color/cccccc). Actually, you can change its `width`, `height`, `background-color`, etc. as you wish.

Comment: I wasn't sure that I understood what you meant by minimised as the I don't get a different icon if the window is minimised. But, if you make the visible part of the browser window smaller, then indeed the navigation menu turns into a button that has three horizontal lines. Thanks for clearing up that mystery for me.

Comment: @Bletch, as you probably figured out, he means "minimized" as in "make the window small", not the usual "minimize to system tray".

Comment: You know what's weird about this... is that it's `.navbar-toggle .icon-bar`. Instead of leaving it as a standalone class, they made it a subclass of the navbar toggle. That, to me, makes no sense. I want to be able to decorate my own buttons and drop-downs with this outside of a navbar. You can just copy the entire CSS block and make it a standalone class to accomplish this, but that's repeated code. I don't know of a better solution, though.

Comment: I can't believe the words _hamburger icon_ don't appear on this page.

Comment: @JeremyAnderson It does now, doesn't it? :D

Answer (score 7):

I expanded on the OP's answer since this came up during a different search, and I had to make a few modifications to actually get things working that I felt were worth sharing here.  Putting it in it's own answer so that it gets proper code formatting.

I used this in a dropdown toggle button instead of navbar (same idea).  Here's the code I used:

HTML:

```
          <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Menu
              <span class="icon-bars-button">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="reservations">Reservations</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="amenities">Amenities</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="accommodations">Accommodations</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="location">Location</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="packages">Packages</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-toggle .icon-bars-button{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.dropdown-toggle .icon-bar {
  margin-bottom:2px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the `class="navbar-toggle"` is used to get the styles.

`data-toggle="collapse"` attribute is used to control the show and hide.

the `data-target = "#id"` attribute is used to connect the button with the collapsible div

`icon-bar` is used o create a button with three horizontal lines. This button is displayed when the screen width is small